# Computing Definite Integrals using Complex Variables and the Residue Therorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I was trying to prove the definite integral $$\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}}\frac{dx\,x\sin{x}}{x^2+a^2}={\pi}e^{-a}$$ by using contour integration and the Residue Theorem. I checked the solution and there I am having a doubt. It says :

> if we consider the integrand as it stands, the contour cannot be closed
>   with a semicircle in either the upper or the lower half-plane, because $\sin{z}$ is a linear
>   combination of $e^{iz}$ and $e^{−iz}$ . If we let $|z|\to\infty$ in the lower half-plane, the term $e^{iz}$ diverges; on the other hand, the term $e^{−iz}$ diverges if $|z|\to\infty$ in the upper half-plane. You can easily get around this difficulty by writing $\sin{z}=\displaystyle{\frac{e^{iz} − e^{−iz}}{2i}}$ and splitting the integral into two integrals. Close the contour in the upper half-plane
>   in the case of $e^{iz}$ and in the lower half-plane in the case of $e^{−iz}$, and pick up the
>   residue at the enclosed pole in each case.

I do not understand that how can the term $e^{iz}$ diverge if we let $|z|\to\infty$ in the lower half plane; after all, for real $x$, $e^{ix}$ diverges as $x\to+\infty$ . So, shouldn't that be $|z|\to\infty$ in the upper half plane to make $e^{iz}$ diverge? Similarly I have doubt for the divergence of the term $e^{-iz}$ .

The solution also states an alternative method :

> Alternatively, you can first write $\sin x$ as the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$, and then
>   consider the integral $\displaystyle{\int_{−\infty}^{\infty}}\frac{dx\,x e^{ix}}{(x^2 + a^2)}$. The contour can now be closed in the
>   upper half-plane (and not in the lower half-plane). After you evaluate the integral,
>   take its imaginary part to get the value of the original integral.

My question is: why should I take the contour in the upper half plane and not in the lower half plane?
Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the usual infinite-semicircle contour encloses imaginary numbers too. Along the negative imaginary axis,$$\lim_{x\to\color{red}{\infty}}e^{ix}=\lim_{\Im x\to-\color{blue}{\infty}}e^{-\Im x}=e^\color{blue}{\infty}=\color{blue}{\infty},$$where the red (blue) $\infty$ is the complex point at infinity (extended real $+\infty$). If this argument is hard to follow, consider e.g. $e^{i(-10000i)}=e^{10000}$ in the lower half of the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are asking for a complex analysis approach but i'd like to share a real method approach using Feynman's trick.

Your integral is
$$I=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{x\sin \left(x\right)}{x^2+a^2}\:dx$$
Now consider the following integral:
$$I\left(b\right)=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{x\sin \left(bx\right)}{x^2+a^2}\:dx$$
$$=\underbrace{\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(bx\right)}{x}\:dx}_{\pi}-a^2\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(bx\right)}{x\left(x^2+a^2\right)}\:dx$$
$$I'\left(b\right)=-a^2\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(bx\right)}{x^2+a^2}\:dx$$
$$I''\left(b\right)=a^2\underbrace{\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{x\sin \left(bx\right)}{x^2+a^2}\:dx}_{I\left(b\right)}$$
$$I''\left(b\right)-a^2I\left(b\right)=0$$
The general form of that differential equation is:
$$I\left(b\right)=C_1e^{ab}+C_2e^{-ab}$$
Now lets find the constants.
$$I\left(0\right)=C_1+C_2=\pi $$
$$I'\left(0\right)=aC_1-aC_2=-\pi a$$
Meaning that $C_1=0$ and $C_2=\pi$
Thus,
$$I\left(b\right)=\pi e^{-ab}$$
$$I=\pi e^{-a}$$

Answer (score 0):

See my post on how to compute this type of integrals using residue's theorem:
[Fourier transform of a rational function using contour integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820349/fourier-transform-of-a-rational-function-using-contour-integration?noredirect=1#comment10258875_4820349)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2047322)